# Access to a object with refs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to access to a ref define with an id

```
:ref="'modal' + item.id"
```

it give me modal123456 when I console log it

In my function I have :

```
function(item) {
    console.log(this.$refs.modal + item)
// I want to have this.$refs.modal123456
}
```

how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending item to value, you should append it to property name instead:

```
console.log(this.$refs[`modal${item.id}`])
```